# JavaFX 2 block mouse property

Tags: mouseevent, javafx, javafx-2

JavaFX 1.x had a blockinMouse property you could set to stop events propagating down to nodes below (for instance a right click to bring up a context menu when you'd just want it on the top node.)

I'm struggling to find an equivalent in JavaFX 2 though, I'm assuming it must be somewhere but the only things I've dug up online have been [similar complaints](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/07/29/where-is-blockinmouse-property-in-javafx-2-0/), and I'd like to avoid the brute force style answer that's listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I was approaching this the wrong way - the solution was to simply call `consume();` on the event in the top most node to stop the event propagating down to the lower nodes. The mouseTransparent property was similar but not what I was after, it just controls whether the node receives mouse events or just passes them on (similar to the old glasspane like approaches.)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaFX 2 this is called: pointerTransparent.

Comment: Didn't you mean mouseTransparent as defined on javafx.scene.Node?